# Sequence of operation for buffered transport in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0

Im trying to understand what actually happens when data is sent in buffered mode (the general steps). Specifically, if the data which is required to be sent is already stored in memory, does WCF create a second copy prior to sending or is there only ever 1 copy stored in memory?

At the client end, im assuming only 1 copy will exist at any point of time as well, assuming thats the case at the server side?